# How to include html comments in WooCommerce email?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I need to include some html comments in the the processing order email sent by WooCommerce:

```
<!--name:Joe Blogs-->
<!--order_id:12345-->
<!--email:joe.bloggs@example.com-->
```

I tried to use

```
<!--name:<?php echo esc_html( $order->get_formatted_billing_full_name() ); ?>-->
<!--order_id:<?php echo esc_html( $order->get_order_number() ); ?>-->
<!--email:<?php echo esc_html( $order->get_billing_email() ); ?>-->
```

But received a fatal warning about an unexpected < in the file.

Could someone tell me how to include these comments?

Thanks

Comment: The code as shown should not throw that error, when it is _outside_ of a `<?php ... ?>` block. If you put it _inside_ of one, then `<!--name...` is of course not valid PHP code.

Comment: hmm ... well this is embarrassing, thanks @CBroe !

Answer (score 0):

As @CBroe guessed, I was using this inside a PHP tag. In my defence, I was modifying someone else's very messy template ;-)